# How to update a docker swarm service with no replication with zero downtime?

Tags: docker, deployment, docker-swarm, downtime

I want to update docker swarm service without down-time. The problem is that I don't have enough resources to have service replication. Is there anyway to do this?

Answer (score 5):

The default with swarm mode is to stop containers before starting new ones. There is a [pull request (#30261)](https://github.com/moby/moby/pull/30261) that was added in 17.05 to optionally start a new instance before stopping the old one. The syntax for this is:

```
docker service update --update-order start-first ...
```

This has not been added to updating stacks yet, you can track that request on [issue #32586](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/32586).

Comment: I think this doesn't work as expected with the vip mode when you curl every second, you may get 502.

Comment: This is the correct answer ! and the best practice - thanks it's really help me

Answer (score 1):

Based on the documentation you can use order property on your docker-service file

**order**: Order of operations during updates :

1. **stop-first** (old task is stopped before starting new one)
2. **start-first** (new task is started first, and the running tasks briefly overlap) (default **stop-first**)

and your docker service file will be like this

```
version: '3.4'
services:
  nginx:
    image: nginx
    restart: always
    deploy:
      restart_policy:
        condition: on-failure
      update_config:
        order: start-first
```

make sure you are using version 3.4+ to make it work

https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#deploy

Answer (score 0):

The type of deploy you want to do is called blue-green deployment. I recommend following the steps of this blog to do it.

https://technologyconversations.com/2017/01/31/blue-green-deployments-with-docker-services-running-inside-a-swarm-cluster/